# Why am I being asked to install the already installed "android-22 SDK platform"?

Tags: android, linux, cordova

Using Linux, I run the command:

`cordova build`

and get the following:

```
[Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running:
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /var/programming/projects/hello/platforms/android/corda/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /var/programming/projects/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit ce 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/corva/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I am running everything as "root" user and have the required environmental variables set.

P.S.

I followed this guide:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Comment: I don't know cordova, but usually you need either `ANDROID_HOME` or `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` set up as environment variable pointing at your android installation.

Comment: Yes you do, however, I already have them set up.  Same error.

Comment: Well, there is one thing I experienced once, that might help. I tried to dex a file on command-line and got a very similar message. For me the reason was: I had installed the sdk through a package manager (homebrew on Mac) and that created a soft link `/usr/local/bin/dx` pointing at a path that got obsolete later (the original path got removed by android package manager, because 'dx' was moved to a different place). So I fixed that link and it worked again.